# X-axis date labels adding breaks on zoom and causing the chart to stutter due to resize

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I have created a graph with plotly-react.

I've set it to auto resize and take up all available space on the screen.

I have enabled zooming by scrolling.

My X axis has dates on it.

Now if I zoom in and out on the graph, the labels can change between showing just the year (2022), to showing the year and a month (Jan 2022), to showing a date, the month and a year (Jan 11, 2022).

In the latter case the label gets displayed with a line break, while in the former two, the label is written on a single line.

This means that when I'm zooming in or out with the scroll, the height of the labels changes between two lines and single line. This causes the whole graph to jump in height, which causes annoying visual stuttering.

I need suggestions on how to fix this issue, and either remove the line breaks in labels, or fix the labels height somehow.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a good workaround?